# Host file doesn't work

Tags: iis, hosts

I have an entry in hosts file with a test domain for a local site and when I ping, it only works with www.domain.dev and when I bind it to a web application (that same application works on Cassini server) in IIS and try to run in browser, it won't work either, and I get:

> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.

So many times before I was working with hosts file without any issues.

I am out of the clues as what might be the problem.

Maybe I am missing something, but I can't see it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this one tripped me up for a few hours one day too. This is what I did to resolve it (Method 1):

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;896861

HTH,
-Brandon

Comment: Thx for the link, but unfortunately, it did not helped me.

Comment: I found out that it was some error with the database which I saw by debugging (another link helped) so the page rendered without css. When I load a static html page, redirects me to a login page with a ReturnUrl as "/" so I tried to log in and that solved the css issue, even if I am logged out, works too.
Some pages render as normal and others redirect me to login page and none of those pages require user to be logged in.
At least, hosts file works. :)
Thanks for your time!